# Python LDAP: The signature algorithm is not supported

Tags: python, django, ssl, ldap, python-ldap

My LDAP authentication stopped working with the following error:

```
{'info': 'The signature algorithm is not supported.', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

It used to work before and the same code still works on OSx and RHEL7. It just doesn't work on my Ubuntu 14.04.

The code below mimics the problem:

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
l = ldap.initialize(url)
l.simple_bind_s(username,pwd)
```

I know this uses self signed certificates.. I wonder if there's a physical place where this certificate is. Deleting it may solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

As suggested by Julien, this looks more an LDAP problem... Using ldapsearch I get the same error message:

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldaps://xxx.xxx.gov/ -b "OU=xxx" -x -d1
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://xxx.xxx.gov/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://xxx.xxx.gov:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP xxx.xxx.gov:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 128.219.164.41:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: can't connect: The signature algorithm is not supported..
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This a LDAP (GNU TLS) problem and not python.
The gnutls26 security update disabled md5 support.
To check if your server is using md5 certificates, run:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect xxx.xxx.xx:636 < /dev/null |  openssl x509 -noout -text > cert.txt

$ cat cert.txt | grep -i signature
Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
```

In the meantime the solution is downgrading the gnutls26 or change (if you can) the certificate provided by your LDAP server.

Answer (score 0):

So weird, I've the SAME issue starting today. I've updated my Ubuntu 14.04 and since, I can't connect to my LDAP server in PHP.

After some diggings, I've the same error as you with the ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://172.22.5.52/ -b "OU=XXX" -x -d5
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://172.22.5.52/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://172.22.5.52:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 172.22.5.52:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 172.22.5.52:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: can't connect: The signature algorithm is not supported..
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Your post make me think that a packet seems broken...

Comment: Same here with ldapsearch... "TLS: can't connect: The signature algorithm is not supported..

Comment: It looks like there's a bug report submitted 2 days ago: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1387330.html